# Ruby / Rails expression. What is self[:reason] in an ActiveRecord class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have found the following expression in a very old piece of code:

```rb
def reason
  self[:reason].try(:to_sym)
end
```

This is a method in an ordinary model class (ultimately) inheriting from ApplicationRecord, nothing fancy.

Can anybody explain to me what `self[:reason]` might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods#[]`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-5B-5D) returns the value of the attribute after it has been typecast

Probably same effect but more readable:

```rb
def reason
  super&.to_sym
end
```

Comment: The fancy pants way would be to create a symbol type for ActiveRecord::Attributes which handles serializing it to/from a string.

Comment: Goodness me. Thanks a lot. They always want the value to be returned as a symbol even if the database stores a string.